# can we use wordpress in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

can i user or integrate wordpress in asp.net, thanking you.

Comment: define "integrate". What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: i want to integrated wordpress in asp.net

Comment: Can somebody else be a moderator?  I don't want to be one anymore.  I just want to crawl under my bed and cry.

Comment: you might want to check this out http://www.microsoft.com/web/wordpress

Answer (score 3):

WordPress is written in PHP so it's not directly compatible with Asp.Net.

You can consume a WordPress blog feed and output it an Asp.Net Web site.

You could also tap into the [WordPress API](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_API%27s)